# Set variables out of anonymous functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I am trying to get a value outside of an anonymous function in Javascript. Basically, I want this function to return 4. I feel like there is an easy fix but I am unsure. Thanks!

```
function a(){
  var x = 1;
  ()=>{
    x = 4;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: You never call the inner function.

Comment: The anonymous function is never called. But why would you use one at all instead of simply `return 4`? Please post your actual code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to invoke the inner function, but since it's anonymous, it has to become an immediately invoked function expression. And, since there is only one statement in the anonymous function, you can omit the curly braces if you like.

```js
function a(){
  var x = 1;
  (() => x = 4)();
  return x;
}

console.log(a());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example defines a function, but nothing is *running* it.  Perhaps try using an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript):

```
function a(){
  var x = 1;
  (()=>{
    x = 4;
  })();
  return x;
}
```

Comment: The last set of parenthesis ()` should be on the outside otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: Thanks, updated.  This was never the case before fat arrow syntax ;)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty weird that you'd want to do this, but just make sure you call the inner function. This can be done using the Immediately-invoked function expression syntax.

```js
function a(){
  var x = 1;
  (()=>{
    x = 4;
  })()
  return x;
}

console.log(a());
```